# MOSFET Based Current Limiter

Tags: power-supply, mosfet, switches, switch-mode-power-supply, current-limiting

I know this question is not new, in fact I learned the basics of this circuit from sites including this one. However I am planning on making a PCB with it and do not have the luxury of multiple attempts at this one. It is to be a 14A at 16V current limiter. This current limiter is going to be used as a desaturation protection on an inductor charging leg in a SMPS Boost converter. I just want to know if there is anything I have missed or any tips in particular? Hopefully a good enough fit for low power loss and low circuit complexity?

PLEASE IGNORE all part numbers and component values. I just drew it using the available components in Circuit Sim.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUA35k.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Thanks

Comment: Also consider what happens when the current limit is exceeded. The feedback shuts off the gate driver. Now the current drops to zero, so the gate driver gets enabled again. What do you think will happen next? (It looks to me like a recipe for oscillation)

Comment: I'm assuming the pin you labeled as 'IN' on the gate driver is actually 'EN' and is low active.

Comment: @AlabaBaju: I've tidied up the schematic for you using GND symbols and flipping the transistor horizontally to minimise the number of crossing wires. You should edit to include the correct component numbers or you will cause much confusion. Double-click the component to edit.

Comment: Yeah Photon I was thinking about the oscillation thing too. That was how it was explained. My understanding was that it would lead to some small ripple on the output. I found that a bit weird too. I added the gate driver because I wanted to at least help with quick turn on and off. Yes the IN pin is the input signal pin. I would clear things up. Thanks

Comment: @Transistor thanks for the help. I would put the question on hold and edit the circuit with accurate component values and part numbers. I didn't think it would cause this much confusion!

Comment: @AlabaBaju: The schematic is key to our understanding. It will only take you a couple of minutes to fix.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of things wrong here:

[image]

1. The opamp is being used open loop, therefore as a comparator.  Due to the offset voltage error, the output is indeterminate at 0 current.  All you know is that with enough current, the output of the opamp will go high.  However, in this case there is no guarantee it will ever go low.

   A TL081 is inappropriate here.  It needs fairly high supply voltage, and then can't drive its output all that close to either rail.  You need to check, but the voltage on R1 might be high enough to be interpreted as high by the gate driver, even when the opamp is driving low.

   The input common mode range of a TL081 doesn't extend to its positive supply.

   I have no idea why you think a emitter follower is needed on the output of the opamp.  It makes no sense.

   You didn't specify the gate driver, but most likely it inteprets its input as a digital signal.  It will either drive the gate fully high or fully low.

   If so, this circuit will oscillate in over-current condition, even if the current detector worked as apparently intended.  When the current gets too high, the FET is turned off.  That makes the current 0, which causes the FET to be turned on again, etc.  This would be undesirable with many loads.

   A 1 mΩ current sense resistor is silly, considering the R<sub>dson</sub> of the FET is 30 mΩ.  Making R2 a bit bigger will give you higher signal to noise ratio of the current feedback, but not substantially add to the voltage drop as long as it remains small compared to the R<sub>dson</sub> of the FET.

Comment: Hi Olin, thanks for the reply. You must have missed it but I wrote 'Please ignore the component values and part numbers'. This is because I just wanted to get a clearer understanding of how the circuit works then I could select components. For example, I just selected a PMOS for symbols sakes, no idea what the IRF9530 ratings are.

Comment: *"Please ignore the component values and part numbers"* It doesn't work that way here.  A schematic is the definitive description of a circuit. Nobody is going to check the text to see if the schematic is supposed to be interpreted differently.

Comment: @OlinLathrop It ***does*** work that way here, because there's a built-in schematic editor that doesn't let you choose the correct part numbers or draw a schematic without part numbers. Go complain on meta.

Comment: @immi: I've never used the built-in schematic editor, but I find that hard to believe.  Surely there is some way to change the name of parts.  I've seen plenty of good schematics created with the built-in editor.  Either way, it's your obligation to post a proper schematic.  A particular tool not being suitable is no excuse.  So use a different tool, obviously.  There are many out there, including some free ones.  Again, there is simply no excuse.

Comment: @OlinLathrop I tried using it *once* and couldn't find any way to change the name of parts. It seems to be geared towards simulation rather than just editing, so presumably it limits you to the selection of parts that it has simulation models for.

Comment: @OlinLathrop Users are accustomed to accepting the limitations of crappy tools they are required to use. It may not have even occurred as a possibility that the asker could use a different tool. (It's also useless to say "use a better tool" without recommending a tool)

Comment: @Imm: Someone accepting the limitation of a crappy tool for their own work is their business.  But it becomes different when they ask others to look at it.  There is no reason I should be inconvenienced because someone else couldn't bother using the right tool for the job.  Recommending one is pointless, since there are so many out there.  Nobody is *required* use the built-in editor.  I don't, for example.  I use Eagle, and properly post-process schematics to post here.  I don't care what others use, so long as the result is correct and easily readable.

Comment: @OlinLathrop Given a choice between "use the conveniently provided schematic editor and get virtually yelled at" and "search around to discover Eagle, download and install it, use its editor, take a screenshot, edit it with any image editor, upload it" I know which one I'd go for - the third option. "don't bother posting your question so everyone loses".

Comment: @imm: No, that's actually fine, even good.  If you can't post properly, don't post.  We get plenty of good questions here, so clearly they are quite possible to write.  Losing a few questions is no big deal.  Losing crappy ones is actually a positive.